# Datepicker, don't lose focus if invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

Not sure if I should start a new question on this, it is a little different than my other post.  I have code to display the datepicker when a user clicks a date field. And, then checks a validation section for 4-digit year. The datepicker allows manual input of the year, as well as selection from the datepicker, because they sometimes enter years well into the future and don't want to have to scroll through calendar years.

If the year of the date is not 4 digits, it gives an error message. However, if they put a 2 digit year, they are clicking tab or the next field with the mouse, so it displays the error message and takes them to the next field anyway, even if the year is invalid. Is there a way to return the focus back to the invalid field if they have tabbed or moused down? Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I've spent hours and hours on this and could just use a little direction.

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker()
        .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
        });
    $('.datepicker2').on('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(keyCode == 9) {
            $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
        }
    });
    ForceDatePickerFormat();
});

function ForceDatePickerFormat() {
    $(".datepicker2").on("blur", function(e) {

        var date, day, month, newYear, value, year;
        value = e.target.value;
        if(value.search(/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/) !== -1) {
            date = e.target.value.split("/");
            month = date[0];
            day = date[1];
            year = date[2];
            if(year === "") {
                year = "0";
            }
            if(year.length < 4 || year.length > 4) {
                alert("Date year must be 4 digits");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried that, but can't find where to place it. I put it right after the alert, but I think by then it is already focused on the next field.

Comment: Have you tried it just after alert or not? Because inside blur handler `this` refers to relevant input so would work

Comment: Yes, I tried it right after the alert. Because it's on."blur", I think the cursor has already moved to the next field.